# ¿Cómo llegó a adquirir "peliagudo" su sentido figurado?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, significado

Según el DRAE:

> **[peliagudo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SNxntVg)**
>
> De *pelo* y *agudo*.
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de un animal: Que tiene el pelo largo y delgado, como el conejo, el cabrito, etc.
> 2. adj. coloq. Dicho de un negocio o de otra cosa: Difícil de resolver o entender.

Ambas acepciones estaban ya presentes en el diccionario de autoridades. La primera acepción parece lógica dada la etimología, siendo la segunda acepción la figurada. Lo que me pregunto es: ¿cómo llegó la palabra a tener esta segunda acepción?

Answer (score 2):

Mi propuesta, sin ningún respaldo: las cosas *agudas* termina en una punta, por lo que pinchan. Los seres con *pelos agudos* son difíciles de tomar con las manos. Pienso en los erizos y las ortigas. (Bueno, también pienso en algunas piernas...).

Algunas situaciones que tenemos que enfrentar son como erizos. Nos cuesta decidirnos a tomarlas y cuando lo hacemos se sienten incómodas y hasta dolorosas, dan ganas de dejarlas. Una ecuación, una pregunta, la organización de mi escritorio, etc., son asuntos "difíciles", como si tuvieran pelos agudos.

Comment: No está mal, pero según el diccionario los seres con pelos agudos son más bien los conejos. Creo que con agudos se referían a finos. Los erizos no tienen pelos, sino púas agudas. El símil debe de referirse a otro tipo de dificultad ocasionado por los seres peliagudos.

Answer (score 1):

Mi hipótesis, sin soporte alguno, sería que se relaciona con [la piel de gallina](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piel_de_gallina).

Si una situación me resulta muy complicada, bien podría ponerme la piel de gallina. Esto última haría que mis pelos del brazo se pusieran en punta, agudos al tacto. Puedo imaginar como en un tiempo muy antiguo la gente hizo la relación y empezó a llamar a las situaciones complicadas, peliagudas.

Answer (score 0):

Expongo mi propia teoría, que no por ello quiero decir que sea válida, para someterla a vuestro criterio (y crítica). Encuentro en el CORDE la siguiente cita:

> *—Si eso es así —dijo Sancho—, vea el señor doctor de cuantos manjares hay en esta mesa cuál me hará más provecho y cuál menos daño, y déjeme comer dél sin que me le apalee; porque por vida del gobernador, y así Dios me le deje gozar, que me muero de hambre, y el negarme la comida, aunque le pese al señor doctor y él más me diga, antes será quitarme la vida que aumentármela.
>
>   —Vuestra merced tiene razón, señor gobernador —respondió el médico—, y, así, es mi parecer que vuestra merced no coma de aquellos conejos guisados que allí están, porque es manjar **peliagudo**. De aquella ternera, si no fuera asada y en adobo, aun se pudiera probar, pero no hay para qué.*
>
> Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra, "Segunda parte del ingenioso caballero don Quijote de la Mancha", España (1615)

La sensación que me da es que estamos ante un juego de palabras. Por un lado, sabemos que los conejos tienen un pelaje peliagudo, según la primera acepción. Pero el doctor le recomienda no tomarlo por ser peliagudo, pero para la salud (segunda acepción). Es posible que ya desde antes se supiera que el exceso de conejo podía provocar males en la salud de las personas que podían permitírselo, y se asociaran los alimentos de animales peliagudos con ser un asunto peliagudo para la salud.

Está algo cogida por los pelos (agudos) la teoría, pero no quería dejar de compartirla.